# How to use Linux as external monitor?

Tags: display

Is there any way I could use a Linux laptop as a secondary display for my MacBook Pro (2016, 13",  macOS High Sierra 10.13.1)?

A solution for any Linux distro would work as I'm willing to install any one on it.

Comment: Maybe something involving VNC screen sharing?

Comment: @seaturtle That's exactly what I don't want - VNC lets me share a screen with another computer, but not make an emulated external monitor there.

Comment: Hm. I believe there's an iOS app that makes your iOS device appear as a screen, so it can be done, somehow....

Comment: Surely this would depend on the hardware of the 'Linux laptop', and also possibly some software on it? As such, it's not really a question about Macs or MacOS.