# Picture-in-picture, but for users?

Tags: user-account, remote-desktop, login, automation

On my Macbook Pro I have three accounts. One is an Administrator account, the other two are standard users: one for all my work-related stuff, while the other is personal. I keep the two completely separate, I’m not even logged to my gmail on the work account.

When I’m using the work account, I still have the need from time to time to access the personal account, e.g. to check the mail or to schedule a doctor appointment.

I personally find the user switch too cumbersome and distracting, **what I’d like ideally is a window to my home user**, that I can open and close when I need without completely switching environment.

I tried to log in my home user with **screen sharing and a VNC viewer** app. While this works in principle, the frame rate and general responsiveness is abysmal.

What could be another solution, or how could I improve the performance to a tolerable level?

Comment: You’re not going to get more “performance” out of user switching.  As far as VNC goes, [it’s a horrible protocol](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460920/119271).  For simple things like checking/responding to email, why not get an iPad?